Statements equivalent to axiom of infinity
In Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory, one of the axioms states:
$\exists I(\emptyset\in I \land \forall x(x\in I \Rightarrow (x\cup\{x\})\in I)$
$I$ can ve called an inductive set.
Having such set, we could choose its minimal subset, which satisfy the condition (by getting an intersection of all inductice subsets of a given one).
We could also prove that such minimal set satisfies Peano axioms:

$0=\emptyset$
$n+1=n\cup\{n\}$

I have two questions:

Is this axiom equivalent (in Zermelo-Fraenkel axiomatic) to the statement "there is a set satisfying Peano axiom with respective successor function".
It can be proven by the axiom of infinity, but does it imply the axiom of infinity? I would try to define the minimal inductive set by recursion principle:
$f(n+1)=f(n)\cup\{f(n)\}$ but I am not sure, if I may, since I can not define a range for the function.
How would you prove, whether the statements are equivalent? Are they equivalent even if we omit the axiom of choice?

Is the axiom of infinity equivalent to existence of real numbers (as far as I understand, it can be true only if the previous statement is equivalent to the axiom of infinity). So, having natural numbers, we can define integers, rational numbers and using e.g. Dedekind construction, build real numbers. Having real numbers, we can consider natural numbers as the minimal inductive subset and prove Peano axioms for it. For this question, I need a full answer, only if I am wrong or missed some crucial parts of the proof.



If you will accept a few departures from standard FOL, departures that you will find in most mathematical textbooks, here are two alternative axioms of infinity:
(1) Assume there exists at least one Dedekind Infinite set $X$:
$\exists X, f, x_0: [\forall a\in X: f(a)\in X~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$($f$ is a function on $X$)
$~~~~~\land ~\forall a,b\in X: [f(a)=f(b) \implies a=b]~~~~$ ($f$ is injective)
$~~~~~\land~ x_0\in X ~~\land~~ \forall a\in X: f(a) \neq x_0~]~~~~~~~~~~~$ ($f$ is not surjective)
From this we can derive Peano's Axioms:
$\exists N, S, 0: [0\in N$
$~~~~~\land \forall a\in N: S(a)\in N$
$~~~~~\land \forall a, b\in N: [S(a)=S(b)\implies a=b]$
$~~~~~~\land \forall P\subset N: [[0 \in P ~\land~ \forall a\in P: S(a)\in P] \implies P = N]$
Where $N\subset X,~0=x_0~$ and $\forall a\in N: S(a)=f(a)$.
(2) Skip the derivation and start with Peano's Axioms with $N$ being the required infinite set.
Note that $N$ can also be shown to be a Dedekind infinite set.
Also, the integer, rational and real numbers can be constructed (i.e. proven to exist) starting from Peano's Axioms as defined above. (See: Dedekind Cuts)

From your second point I can give you a partial answer. It depends on the way you define $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose we have constructed them through Dedekind cuts, then since $\mathbb{N}\subset \mathbb{R}$, the natural numbers would be Dedekind cuts, for instance, $1=(L_1,U_1)$, is $\mathbb{N}$ an inductive set? Does $1\cup \{1\}\in \mathbb{N}$? Clearly not since $1\cup \{1\}= (L_1,U_1)\cup \{(L_1,U_1)\}$ which is not a Dedekind cut.
I think assuming that $\mathbb{N}$ is constructed as $0=\emptyset$, $1=\{\emptyset\} $ and so on is already assuming that the axiom of infinity holds and doesn't count as derivation from the existence of real numbers.
